# ionic 2 grid problems with col-* / respnosive

Tags: ionic2, flexbox, grid-layout

I've got this code

```
<ion-grid>
      <ion-row wrap> 
        <ion-col col-2>
          <h3>Adresse</h3>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-1 offset-1>
          <h3>Telefon</h3> 
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-4>
          <h3>Geb./Fam./Adelspräd.</h3>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <h3>Beruf/Stellung/Titel</h3>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <h3>KNR/Inhaber</h3>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

but it doesn't do anything with col-* attributes, like it's described in here
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/
I can't find any called css-classes. There just 5 cols with the same width

Bet when I take width-10, it reacts to what I'm doing.

At the end, I want something like this

```
<ion-col col-12 col-sm>
  1 of 4
</ion-col>
```

to get it responsive.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams, that ionic doesn't support the whole flexbox-grid, and just knows the classes like `width-*`.

To use the whole power of the flexbox-grid, I imported the original flexbox css-file and everything works fine.

[website of the flexbox-grid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
width-10
```

Instead of

```
col-10
```

Comment: It would have a different effect. width-10 means 10% of the row col-10 means 83.333% of the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with the Ionic Responsive Grid. The solution is to use classes as you would attributes (as [provided by Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/responsive-grid/)). So:

instead of

```
<ion-col col-3>
 This is apparently an ionic column of 25% width.
</ion-col>
```

you would use

```
<ion-col class="col-3">
 This is apparently an ionic column of 25% width.
</ion-col>
```

You can also combine attributes:

```
<ion-col class="col-12 col-md-5 offset-1 col-lg-6">
 This is an ionic column of 100% width for all screens **up to** medium size, 41% with 8.3% offset for all screens medium to large, and 50% for large screens upwards.
</ion-col>
```

This should do the trick. And remember, your ionic columns [should always be inside ionic rows, inside grids](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#how-it-works).